# So what's the point of the moderator election?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Don't get me wrong, I like all our nominees and am glad to see volunteers step up to support the site.  But, with three candidate positions and only three nominees, I'm not sure why we're actually having an *election* for eight days.  Aren't all the candidates automatically going to win?

On other sites, elections were delayed a bit to have at least one more nominee than positions available.  Is that going to happen here (with the election being paused), or should we just go ahead and vote anyway?

Comment: It seems that 45 users have already voted: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/badges/92/constituent

Comment: They could technically always scrap it and redo it.  I just don't know what the vote is for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, normally, when a moderator election has fewer than N+1 candidates, where N is the number of seats available, we extend the nomination phase by one week to allow for more people to nominate. Usually I'm good to pay attention to this when making the transition. However, in the process of setting up the Stack Overflow and Music elections while also coordinating the graduation processes for five other sites, I skimmed past the candidate count here and unfortunately did not trigger the process to extend the nomination phase.

I'm not sure what we're going to do to fix this and get things back into the nomination phase. Nor do I know what impact it'll have on votes that may've already been cast. Looking into it.

---

### Update

[Check out the new announcement regarding the change](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/restarting-the-election-nomination-phase-for-2015-moderator-election). It's not exactly a smooth transition we've got going, and it's resulted in some sort of weird mid-week phase change, but this should fix it all up.

Comment: I don't know if this has come up yet, but what happens in the event there are no additional nominations and we don't make it to N+1?  Do you give _another_ weeklong extension?

Comment: First, we cry a little bit, @Troyen. But then, yeah, probably.

Comment: It's either an extension or we kill the election and have like, a campfire on Meta as we try to figure out why no one is nominating, or otherwise how to proceed.