# Restarting the Election Nomination Phase for 2015 Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election

[We sorta had a snafu with the election](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/so-whats-the-point-of-the-moderator-election) - namely we let the election persist into the election phase without enough candidates to actually have an election. The normal process, as happened over on [Personal Finance](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/moderator-elections-we-need-more-candidates), is to extend the nomination phase for an additional week to attempt to gain enough candidates to reach N+1 candidates for N slots. However, because of poor planning resulting in a singular point of failure, and that singular point of failure in fact failing... we did not extend the nomination phase - and furthermore didn't become aware of this fact for multiple days. This has resulted in people already voting for the candidates - which is a good show of support for the three in spite of the fact that they would all be elected by default.

Still. We messed up. Sorry about that.

### What happens now?

We can't simply roll back the election due to the progress it's already made. In order to produce a new nomination phase, we are **terminating the existing election and starting a new one**. This new one will be starting at 23:00 UTC (so at the turn of the hour). All of the existing nominations are being copied over to the new election, and the new nomination phase will run for a full week once again. This unfortunately nixes all the voting that had happened previously, although the data remains available as the previous election remains in the system.

### What should I do now?

- Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? **Please consider running!**
- Do you know of users who you think would be great moderators, but who have not stepped up? **Encourage them to run!**

Moderatorship is a position of leadership, but one of the most important aspects is that it is something that comes from the community - we need not just the support of the community to elect them, but also for you to be the people who stand up to the task.

A week from now, voting will begin anew (you'll have to re-cast your vote then if you already voted this week).

Again, I apologize for the confusion and thank you all for the patience you've shown while we've worked to correct this mistake.